# VHDL: if statement inside for generate

Tags: vhdl

Is it valid to write an if statement inside a for-generate statement in VHDL?

For example

```
architecture Behavioral of top_level is
begin

    label: for ii in 0 to (width - 1) generate
        if ii = 0 then
            ... do this
        end if;
    end generate;

end Behavioral;
```

This produces a syntax error `warning: syntax error near if` - so I'm wondering if `if` statements cannot be nested inside a `for-generate` statement in VHDL.

If so is there another method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `if..generate` for a conditional generate. `if..then` can only be used in procedural code, ie. inside a `process`, `function` or `procedure`.